# SAS macro program : accounting for database indexed by both numbers and characters

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am working on a project in wich i have data at a particular geographical level. Due to historical reasons, these areas are indexed as :

01
02
...
19
**2A**
**2B**
21
...
95

I have a program I want to run on each of these areas, for which the database is indexed sthg_d**theindex** (sthg_d01; sthg_d2A...), and merge them with a national database for which I have this index of geographical area (it is *dep*)

For now what I have done is to create a table with corresponding indexes 
(1:01 ; 2:02 ; 19 : 19 ; 20 : 21 ; 28 : 29 ; 29 : 2A ; 30 : 2B ; 31 : 30...)
and I then try to merge by searching each file in this list. It works for the numerical indexes, but infortunately it does not work for the two indexes in character, I get

```
ERROR 388-185: Opérateur arithmétique requis.
ERROR 202-322: L'option ou le paramètre n'est pas reconnu(e) et sera ignoré(e).
```

Which is in english:

```
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Here is my code

```
%macro appar ();  

data _null_;
set dep.dep2; /*the table with (1:01 ; 2:02 ; 19 : 19 ; 20 : 21 ; 28 : 29 ; 29 : 2A ; 30 : 2B ; 31 : 30...) */
call symput('d'!!left(_n_),dep2); /* variable with 01;02;... is called dep2 */
run;

%do i=1 %to 96 ;  /* 2 pour tester sinon 96 sur la métropole */

/* I try to create my subtable i of the national one */
data f(keep = dep dirindik);
    set FoyerN.foyer;
    length dep $2;
    dep=substr(dirindik,1,2);
    if dep=&&&d&i;
run;
```

**It is here that I have my problem, in the *if dep=&&&d&i* .**

```
/* The core of my problem : the merge */ 
data p;
    merge f(in=x) PotePrec.pote&anprec._d&&d&i (in=y);
    by dirindik;
    if x and y;
run;


%end; /* du %do */
%mend appar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dep` is defined as $2 character variable, it needs to be compared to string constant like this:

```
if dep="&&&d&i";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "&&d&i"?  With three ampersands, I would think SAS tries to resolve &d on the first resolution pass.